# Adding google-profanity-words to web page

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to add https://github.com/coffee-and-fun/google-profanity-words to my website, but the only option I see is using Node.js which is not option for me since I need to install it on server and using from there(correct me if I am wrong)

I found some cdn like this one - https://www.skypack.dev/view/@coffeeandfun/google-profanity-words But didn't manage to get it to work.

I tried it like this -

```
import { ProfanityEngine } from '@coffeeandfun/google-profanity-words';

let profanity = new ProfanityEngine();

profanity.all(); // returns all bad words as an array.

profanity.search('bad word'); // returns true if the word is found in the list.
```

But getting an error that ProfanityEngine is not defined.

Can you please provide an example that this works on web page?

Comment: We need more context to understand the question. Are you running a node.js server ?

Comment: @underscore sorry for not mentioning that, no node js server.